# HTML List Box not displaying correct selected option

Tags: html, mysql

I have a query that selects a list of colors from a table. The select statement is `SELECT ColorDesc, ColorCode FROM Colors ORDER BY ColorCode`.

A sample of the data in the table is:

```
ColorDesc, ColorCode
Select Color -#0
Black -#000000
Navy -#000080
DarkBlue -#00008B
MediumBlue -#0000CD
Blue -#0000FF
DarkGreen -#006400...
```

When the list is returned the listbox returns the correct options however the display option is defaulted to 'Black' when it should be 'Select Color'.

Resulting HTML (updated 2012.12.26):

```
<label for="skinColorId">Select Skin Color</label>      
                                    <select id="skinColorId" name="skinColorId" title="Select Skin Color">
                                    <option value="#000000" selected="selected">Select Color</option><option value="#00FFFF">Aqua</option><option value="#7FFFD4">Aquamarine</option><option value="#F0FFFF">Azure</option><option value="#F5F5DC">Beige</option><option value="#FFE4C4">Bisque</option><option value="#000000" selected="selected">Black</option><option value="#FFEBCD">BlanchedAlmond</option><option value="#0000FF">Blue</option><option value="#8A2BE2">BlueViolet</option><option value="#A52A2A">Brown</option><option value="#DEB887">BurlyWood</option><option value="#5F9EA0">CadetBlue</option><option value="#7FFF00">Chartreuse</option><option
```

JSP Code (updated 2012.12.26):

```
<li>
<form:label for="skinColorId" path="skinColorId">Select Skin Color</form:label>     
                                        <form:select path="skinColorId" id="skinColorId" title="Select Skin Color">
                                        <form:options items = "${skinColor.skinColorList}" itemValue="colorCode" itemLabel="colorDesc"/>
                                        </form:select>          
                                        <form:errors path="skinColorId" class="errors"/><label class="colorPreviewer" id="skinColorPreviewer">color previewer</label>
</li>
```

Updated (2012/12/27)

When i set 'Select Color' to #000000 and 'Black' to #000000 the select list shows Black as the selected value and Black is displayed in the list instead. However when i set 'Select Color' to #FFFFFF and 'Black' to #FFFFFF both the same values the default value is 'Select Color'. Why?

Comment: Show the resulting HTML.

Comment: it has the correct resulting values i dont know why the display is defaulting to BLACK as the display value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two selected attributes in use, so the second one is the one that is selected, and not the intended 'Select Color'. Remove `selected="selected"` from the following and try again.. :)

```
<option value="#000000" selected="selected">Black</option>
```

Comment: I cannot remove the selected=selected because the items are being selected from the database and the selected ="selected" is being created on its own. I changed the colorCode for 'Select Color' to #0 and still same result

Comment: does 'Select Color' need a colorCode at all? Does it make a difference if you remove it or change it to something like #6. You could also add the 'Select Color' option at the end of the loop so it is manually added once all the other options have been generated. From a brief look at your code it seems the same colodCode is the issue, but if you have already tried that...

Comment: my guess is that #0 and #000000 are both evaluating to the same result. so a more unique value for 'Select Color' such as #ffffff may solve the issue.

Comment: When i set 'Select Color' to #000000 and 'Black' to #000000 the select list shows Black as the selected value and Black is displayed in the list instead. However when i set 'Select Color' to #FFFFFF and 'Black' to #FFFFFF both the same values the default value is 'Select Color'. Why?

Comment: good question! Did using a unique value or omitting the value for 'Select Color', or placing the option outside the loop, do anything?

Comment: i used the value 0 for 'Select Color' and Black to '#000000' and this worked for me. I realized that i had some values in the list that were not unique and this was causing problems in the list this is why the list kept juggling values and changing the display value

Comment: i did not set the 'Black' option to selected or hardcode this option since the list is from the database table and it already has a 'Black' option and if that table is emptied at any time and a user not knowing whats happening in the code adds 'Black' to the table it will be a duplicate value. Although i can set constraints to the table to not allow it, but the PK is of type string and a user may do anything to get the value in.